# Listing github directory with python

Tags: python, html, file, github, download

Is there some kind of a web-request or something like that so I can list a directory in my github repository in python? I have to check for few files if they are there and they are pretty large so I don´t want to try to download them in my app. I have to just check if they are there.

The only way to do this that I found is to download the html file and then checking right in that file using BeautifulSoup. But this is not very elegant way to do so. In addition I have some troubles with installing BeautifulSoup package for python.

Right now I am using a txt file in which there are all the dlls listed. I run simple script before each commit that generates this text file.

**EDIT:**
I found a solution with the help of PyGithub

```
from github import Github

g = Github("token")
for repo in g.search_repositories("XtremeUpdater"):
     for file in repo.get_contents("dir"):
          print(file.name)
```

Comment: Simply check if a GET request returns a 404 or not? On GitHub the URL would be `https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/blob/master/path/to/the/file`

Comment: Well, and if not, it will download the file of course. :/

Comment: Maybe look at GitHub's API. And if the file is very large, GitHub does not display it. Depends on what your size threshold is.

Comment: Ok. So I downloaded PyGithub but I can't found anywhere anything about even a directory.

Comment: In PyGitHub docs: https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.get_contents and https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.get_dir_contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `get_dir_contents` method worked for me:

```
import github
g = github.Github("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
repo = g.get_user().get_repo( "REPO_NAME" )
print repo.get_dir_contents("")
```